# Checking if the UIPickerView is shown or hidden? The *if* conditions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sdk, uipickerview

I have a little problem with my UIPickerView animation.
I did set up the animation so when I click a button the UIPickerView will slide up and after another click it will slide down. But I hit the problem on *if*. I tried to set up a new settings bool and set it's value after each animation, so the *if* was just checking for the bool. I'm not sure if I did explained it well, but maybe you get the idea from the code.
But unfortunately it's not working... Any ideas?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [settings setBool:NO forKey:@"pickerShown"];
    [settings synchronize];
}


- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender {

    CGRect rect = countryPicker.frame;
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0, 510); // Some off-screen y-offset here.

    rect.origin = origin;
    countryPicker.frame = rect;


    if ([settings boolForKey:@"pickerShown"] == YES) {


        // Perform transform to slide it off the screen.
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        countryPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -0); // Offset.
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [settings setBool:NO forKey:@"pickerShown"];
        [settings synchronize];

    } else if ([settings boolForKey:@"pickerShown"] == NO) {


        // Perform transform to slide it onto the screen.
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        countryPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -266); // Offset.
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [settings setBool:YES forKey:@"pickerShown"];
        [settings synchronize];

    }
}
```

EDIT:

Just found the solution...
If anyone's interested - here it is:

The h. file:

```
.
.
.
{
BOOL pickerShown;
}
.
.
.
```

The .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect = countryPicker.frame;
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0, 510); // Some off-screen y-offset here.

    rect.origin = origin;
    countryPicker.frame = rect;
pickerShown = NO;


}


- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender {


    if (pickerShown == NO) {


        // Perform transform to slide it onto the screen.
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        //[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(hidePicker)];
        countryPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0); // Offset.
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self performSelector:@selector(hidePicker) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

    } else if (pickerShown == YES) {

        //countryPicker.hidden = NO;
        // Perform transform to slide it onto the screen.
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        countryPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -266); // Offset.
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        countryPicker.hidden = NO;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution... If anyone's interested - here it is:

The h. file:

```
.
.
.
{
BOOL pickerShown;
}
.
.
.
```

The .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect = countryPicker.frame;
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0, 510); // Some off-screen y-offset here.

    rect.origin = origin;
    countryPicker.frame = rect;
pickerShown = NO;


}


- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender {


    if (pickerShown == NO) {


        // Perform transform to slide it onto the screen.
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        //[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(hidePicker)];
        countryPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0); // Offset.
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self performSelector:@selector(hidePicker) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

    } else if (pickerShown == YES) {

        //countryPicker.hidden = NO;
        // Perform transform to slide it onto the screen.
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        countryPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -266); // Offset.
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        countryPicker.hidden = NO;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If a view is visible on screen, it's `window` property will be non-nil.

Answer (score 2):

You can check it with:

```
self.countryPicker.superview
```

If picker is hidden then superview will be nil. Otherwise it will be containing view.

Comment: simple and efficient  - and sneaky - I like it - works perfectly for me - thank you

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the basic effect of displaying the picker view, then removing it again there is an easier way.

pseudocode:

```
//do any picker initialization here

if(!pickerIsShowing)
[self.view addSubview:yourPickerView];
else
 [self.yourPickerView removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: Sorry, thats not what I meant. I don't want to remove the picker, just needed to move it off the screen and back :)) Nevermind, I've just found the solution :)

Comment: @DomiNickHádl: Please post your solution for the benefit of others.